# How do i multiply numbers in Type Script in a array like [{ count: 3, value: 2 },{ count: 7, value: 1 }] such that the answer is 3*2 + 7*1 = 13?

Tags: javascript

Assuming I have this array:

`[{ count: 3, value: 2 },{ count: 7, value: 1 }]`

How do I multiply numbers such that the answer is 13?

I want to code to do:

```
3*2 + 7*1 = 13
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) for doing this:

```js
const arr = [{ count: 3, value: 2 },{ count: 7, value: 1 }];
const val = arr.reduce((acc, item) => acc + (item.count * item.value), 0);

console.log(val);
```

You can also do this on all keys (e.g. not only count and value) using this code:

```js
const arr = [{ count: 3, value: 2 },{ count: 7, value: 1 }];
const val = arr.reduce((acc, item) => acc + Object.values(item).reduce((a,b) => a * b, 1), 0);

console.log(val);
```